# Workaround for max with partition by

Tags: sql, denodo

I am working on the denodo views (Querying the oracle DB) and the max function along with partition by does not work. I am looking for a workaround for this query. This query worked fine a few days back but recently I am getting the max function is not an executable error.

```
   select
    case WHEN ((current_date-max((ccst.screened_dtm) OVER ( PARTITION BY ccst.name, ccst.id )) < 30)) 
    THEN 'Screened in 30' ELSE 'Not Screened in Last 30' END AS l_30_srnd
    or current_date-max(completed_dtm) over (partition by study_name ,id ) < 30
    or current_date-max(screened_dtm) over (partition by study_name ,site_id ) < 30
    then 'Active in Last 30 '
    else 'No Activity in Last 30 ' end as r_f
    
FROM site_v1 AS ccis LEFT OUTER JOIN subjects_v1 AS ccst 
ON ccis.name = ccst.name 
AND ccis.code = ccst.code 
AND ccis.id = ccst.id
```

Data:

```
screened_dtm   name           id
2017-01-20    011001         2001 
2013-01-21    D52-PL10018    2202
2015-01-21    D52-PL1        3454
```

Error:

```
 Finished with error: Error executing view: Function max is not executable
```

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to answer your question because it is not clear what columns come from which tables.

Comment: Updated it @Gordon linoff

Answer (score 0):

The *max* function, as any other analytical function, could be pushed down to a data source to be executed but the server can't execute it.

I would recommend you to review the "Delegate analytic functions list" of the data source and ensure that it contains the max function.